# Check if a SQL Select statement returns no rows

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a select statement

```
SELECT     QBalance
FROM         dbo.CustomerBalance
WHERE     (CustomerID = 1) AND (MarchentID = @MerchantId)
```

I want to check if that statement returns 0 rows. I tried to use the ISNULL and IFNULL but it seems that I'm missing something.

Comment: By Null do you mean no rows, or an actual `Null` value in QBalance? And what would you like to do if you get null?

Comment: To help you in the future, no rows is different than null. (You should edit this question to change to No Rows, and specify what you'd like to happen.)

Comment: ok thanks, thats what I've done and it works fine

`DECLARE @NULL int

SET @NULL= (SELECT COUNT    (QBalance)

FROM         dbo.CustomerBalance

WHERE     (CustomerID = @CustomerID) AND (MarchentID = @MerchantId))
   
   
IF @NULL=0

   BEGIN
 Insert into [CustomerBalance]([CustomerID],[MarchentID],[QBalance],[InitialDate]) VALUES(@CustomerID,@MerchantId,@CodeQPoints,GETDATE())
   END
   ELSE
   UPDATE [CustomerBalance]
   SET QBalance=@CodeQPoints+QBalance,InitialDate=GETDATE()  
   WHERE dbo.CustomerBalance.CustomerID=@CustomerID and dbo.CustomerBalance.MarchentID=@MerchantId`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

To find out whether no matching rows exist you can use `NOT EXISTS`. Which can be more efficient than counting all matching rows

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ...)
BEGIN
PRINT 'No matching row exists'
END
```

Answer (score 14):

If this is SQL Server, try [@@ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT    COUNT(*) 
FROM         dbo.CustomerBalance 
WHERE     (CustomerID = 1) AND (MarchentID = @MerchantId)
```

If you get 0, you got 0.  :)

Comment: any efficient way to do so

Comment: see the accepted answer, or look at your indexing strategy.

Answer (score 6):

You can use @@ROWCOUNT. For e.g.

```
SELECT     QBalance
FROM         dbo.CustomerBalance
WHERE     (CustomerID = 1) AND (MarchentID = @MerchantId)

--This will return no of rows returned by above statement.
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

You will get 0 if first statement will not return any rows. You can also use if statement to check that just after first statement. e.g.

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 0 
  PRINT 'Select statement is returning some rows'
ELSE 
  PRINT 'No rows returned'
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
SELECT     ISNULL(QBalance, 'ReplaceValue')
FROM         dbo.CustomerBalance
WHERE     (CustomerID = 1) AND (MarchentID = @MerchantId)
```

Comment: Very simple, very nice

Comment: @Jordan_Walters - It doesn't work though. If no rows exist there is no value to apply `ISNULL` on.

Answer (score 0):

Could also use an outer ISNULL check?

```
SELECT ISNULL((
SELECT QBalance
FROM   dbo.CustomerBalance
WHERE  (CustomerID = 1) AND (MarchentID = @MerchantId)), 0)
```